# Finding the no. of possible matrices given the order and limited no. of entries

Tags: matrices, permutations

The no. of all possible matrices of order $3\times 3$ with each entry $0$ and $1$ and $ -1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given $n\times n$ matrix with restricted $m$ elements, then number of possible matrices is $$m^{(n^2)}$$ because there are $n^2$ places to fill with $m$ choices.

In this case both $n=m=3$, therefore $3^9$ matrices.

Answer (score 5):

There are $9$ entries in the matrix and there are  $3$ choices for each entry. We get to choose whether it takes value $0$, $1$ or $-1$ independently.

Hence number of possible matrices $=3^{9}$.